# Change element between cells of a table

Tags: javascript, function, html-table, cell

I'm creating a table with two fields, and I'm trying to do:

- When I register an user, the username will be displayed, with this username when I click a button, the cell field will be filled with the username and the button will be hidden (ok until now).
- When I click on the button of the second cell, this data will be passed to that cell and the past cell will be reset to the first name.

This second part I'm trying but seems impossible, what I can do for solve this?

```js
<script>
var list = document.getElementById('users');

function addUser(){
    var username = document.getElementById('username').value;
    var entry = document.createElement('li');
    entry.appendChild(document.createTextNode(username));
    list.appendChild(entry);
    
    return false;
}
var hidden = false;
function teste(){
hidden = !hidden;
        if(hidden) {
            document.getElementById('testebut').style.visibility = 'hidden';
   var coe = document.getElementById('username').value;
   document.getElementById('lbl1').innerHTML = "user: " + coe;
   
        } else {
            document.getElementById('testebut2').style.visibility = 'visible';
        }
  }
</script>
```

```css
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
```

```html
<html>
<head>

</head>

<body>

  <fieldset>
    <form id="myform" onsubmit="return addUser()">
    <h2>Add a User:</h2>
    <input id="username" type="text" name="username" placeholder="name"/>
        <input id="email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="email"/>
    <button type="submit">add user</button>
</form>
        
<h2>UsersList:</h2>
<ul id="users"></ul>
  </fieldset>
  
  <table>
  <tr>
    <th>User</th>
 <th>User</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td id="lbl1">---<button id="testebut" onClick="teste();">X</button></td>
 <td id="lbl2">---<button id="testebut2">X</button></td>

 </tr>
 </table>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Can you explain the second part of the question with an example of the output/result that you expect?

Comment: I.ex: I have an user called: "John", if i click on button 1, The td lbl1 will be called John... if i click on button 2, the td lbl2 will be called  John and the lbl1 will be called ----.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made several changes to your code to achieve what in my opinion is you needed. Instead of events in HTML I created some event listeners using JavaScript. I hope this is of help to you.

```html
<html>
<head>
  <style>
      table, th, td {
        border: 1px solid black;
      }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <fieldset>
    <form id="myform" >
    <h2>Add a User:</h2>
    <input id="username" type="text" name="username" placeholder="name"/>
        <input id="email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="email"/>
    <button type="submit" id="addUserBtn">add user</button>
</form>
        
<h2>UsersList:</h2>
<ul id="users"></ul>
  </fieldset>
  
  <table>
  <tr>
    <th>User</th>
 <th>User</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>
    <span id="lbl1">---</span>
    <button id="testebut">X</button>
  </td>
  
 <td>
    <span id="lbl2">---</span>
    <button id="testebut2">X</button>
  </td>

 </tr>
 </table>
  </body>
  </html>
  
  <script>
  
  var list = document.getElementById('users');

if ( document.getElementById( "addUserBtn" ) ) {
 document.getElementById( "addUserBtn" ).addEventListener( "click", function( e ) {
   //prevent the page from reloading and add the user to the list
    e.preventDefault();
    addUser();
  });
}

function addUser(){
    var username = document.getElementById('username').value;
    var entry = document.createElement('li');
    entry.appendChild(document.createTextNode(username));
    list.appendChild(entry);
}

//get all the teste buttons
let testeButtons = document.querySelectorAll( "button[id^='testebut']" );
//add event listener to all the teste buttons
for ( let i = 0; i < testeButtons.length; i++ ) {
 testeButtons[ i ].addEventListener( "click", function( e ) {
   teste( e.target.id );
  });
}

function teste( id ){
    let resetField = "---";
     
      //this will only get the last username in the list
      let userName = document.getElementById('username').value;
      
      //check if clicked button is testebut and that it's not hidden
      //then add the user name to the field and reset the other field
   if ( id === "testebut" ) {
        document.getElementById( "lbl1" ).innerHTML = "user: " + userName;
          document.getElementById( "lbl2" ).innerHTML = resetField;
          
          
      } else if ( id === "testebut2" ) {
        document.getElementById( "lbl2" ).innerHTML = "user: " + userName;
          document.getElementById( "lbl1" ).innerHTML = resetField;
      }
  }
    
    </script>
```

Comment: This code works perfectly, I will study all implemented changes. Thank you.

Comment: Can I use the same logic to do this in JQuery? (For instantly update on the client)

Comment: Yes, I think that it should not be a problem. It is simply my own personal preference to write in plain JavaScript. If something is not clear in my code, feel free to let me know and I will try to explain. Also if this has help you, please considering marking it as correct answer.